# Angular 2 Cannot find the '@angular/common/http' module

Tags: angular

I am trying to import `HttpRequest`, `HttpHandler`, `HttpEvent`, `HttpInterceptor` using the following line :

```
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from @angular/common/http';
```

However I keep getting the same error:

> Cannot find the '@angular/common/http' module

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "coreui",
  "version": "1.0.0-alpha.4",
  "description": "Open Source Bootstrap Admin Template",
  "author": "",
  "url": "http://coreui.io",
  "copyright": "Copyright 2017 creativeLabs Łukasz Holeczek",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {

  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.9",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.9",
    "chart.js": "2.5.0",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.4.0",
    "ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "7.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.2.0",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "7.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "3.2.0",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "0.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "2.1.0",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "typescript": "2.2.1"
  },
  "main": "karma.conf.js"
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Remove `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and run `npm install`.

Comment: So far I know `@angular/common/http` is available since version 4.3+, for version 2 you should use `@angular/http`, but not sure if those objects will be available on it.

Comment: @elvin They are not available on it ..

Comment: Yeah, so if you want to implement an interceptor, you'll have to extend from Http, it works, the difference with later versions is that is cleaner to implement and you avoid some dependency redundancy issues when inheriting from Http.

Comment: did you import HttpClientModule ?

Comment: can  you show us your package.json file ?

Comment: do you still have the problem?